# Ring structure induced by a bijection

Tags: isabelle

Given a ring, together with a bijection to another set (n.b. set not type), it ought to be "trivial" to define the (unique) induced ring structure on the "other set" that makes the bijection an isomorphism. But my proof that tries to use this takes 101 lines (plus definitions and lemmas). Is there another approach using e.g. "lifting" that makes the whole thing fall out more easily?

Here's an example that could be filled in to do what I want:

```
theory InducedRing
  imports "HOL-Algebra.QuotRing"
begin

lemma
  assumes "ring ℛ" "bij_betw φ (carrier ℛ) S"
  obtains  where "ring " and "carrier  = S" and "φ ∈ ring_hom ℛ "
  sorry

end
```

Feel free to rewrite this to an equivalent or stronger statement (e.g., reverse the direction of `\<phi>` or even assume a pair of inverse bijections, make the hypotheses part of a locale definition, assert uniqueness of `\<S>`, change the names according to your own taste....)

The goal is to make the proof feel short and natural. I'm hoping there's a theorem somewhere in `HOL-Algebra` or another library that will make this easy, but sledgehammer was not able to find it for me -- at least, not with this version of the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you will get around proofing the ring axioms, except if someone has already proven a similar lemma. I have no experience with HOL-Algebra, so maybe there is something nicer.

Luckily automation seems to handle them fairly well (except one, where `auto` needs a bit of help). I obtained the proofs by hitting the goal with `auto` and sledgehammering what was left to search for relevant lemmas to add to `auto`.

```
lemma
  assumes "ring ℛ" "bij_betw φ (carrier ℛ) S"
  obtains  where "ring " and "carrier  = S" and "φ ∈ ring_hom ℛ "
proof-
  interpret ℛ: ring ℛ 
    using assms(1) .

  (* Define the ring *)
  let ?Z = "φ (zero ℛ)"
  let ?O = "φ (one ℛ)"
  let ?mult = "λx y . φ (inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ x ⊗⇘ℛ⇙ inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ y)" 
  let ?add = "λx y . φ (inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ x ⊕⇘ℛ⇙ inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ y)" 
  let ? = "⦇ carrier = S, mult = ?mult , one = ?O, zero = ?Z, add = ?add, 
    … = (undefined :: 'd) ⦈ :: ('c, 'd) ring_scheme"
  
  show thesis
  proof(rule that[of ?])
    (* The only part where auto needed some help *)
    have helper: "∃y∈S. φ (inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ x ⊕⇘ℛ⇙ inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ y) = φ ⇘ℛ⇙" 
      if "x ∈ S" for x 
      using assms that by (intro bexI[where x="φ (⊖⇘ℛ⇙ (inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ x))"])
        (auto intro: bij_betw_apply 
          simp add: ring.ring_simprules bij_betw_imp_inj_on bij_betw_imp_surj_on inv_into_into)
      
    show "ring ?"
      using assms by unfold_locales 
        (auto intro: bij_betw_apply simp add: ring.ring_simprules bij_betw_inv_into_right 
          bij_betw_imp_inj_on bij_betw_imp_surj_on inv_into_into Units_def helper)
  next
    show "carrier ? = S"
      by simp
  next
    from assms(2) show "φ ∈ ring_hom ℛ ?"
      by (intro ring_hom_memI) (auto intro: bij_betw_apply simp add: bij_betw_inv_into_left)
  qed
qed
```

In my proof (and yours as well) I explicitly give the definitions of the induced ring, which makes the `obtains` in the goal statement a bit pointless in my opinion. Similarly, the `S` can be computed from `carrier ℛ`. So why not have the concrete definitions available on the toplevel, similar to for example this:

```
abbreviation "bij_ring ℛ φ ≡ ⦇carrier = φ ` carrier ℛ, 
    mult = λx y . φ (inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ x ⊗⇘ℛ⇙ inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ y), one = φ (one ℛ), 
    zero = φ (zero ℛ), add = λx y . φ (inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ x ⊕⇘ℛ⇙ inv_into (carrier ℛ) φ y), 
    … = (undefined :: 'd) ⦈ :: ('c, 'd) ring_scheme"

lemma
  assumes "ring ℛ" "bij_betw φ (carrier ℛ) (φ ` (carrier ℛ))"
  shows "ring (bij_ring ℛ φ)" and "φ ∈ ring_hom ℛ (bij_ring ℛ φ)"
proof-
  interpret ℛ: ring ℛ 
    using assms(1) . 
  (* Sadly it still needs help *)
  from assms have helper: "∃x∈carrier ℛ. φ (y ⊕⇘ℛ⇙ x) = φ ⇘ℛ⇙" 
    if "y ∈ carrier ℛ" for y 
    using that by (metis ℛ.add.r_inv_ex)

  from assms show "ring (bij_ring ℛ φ)"
    by unfold_locales (auto simp add: bij_betw_inv_into_left
        ℛ.add.m_assoc bij_betw_imp_inj_on ring.ring_simprules Units_def helper)
  from assms(2) show "φ ∈ ring_hom ℛ (bij_ring ℛ φ)"
    by (intro ring_hom_memI) (auto intro: bij_betw_apply simp add: bij_betw_inv_into_left)
qed
```

This also seems to simplify the proofs a bit. Sadly there is some duplication in the goal statement, but I cannot see a way to improve this now.

Comment: Nice use of auto! I did not know you could add assumptions to auto in so many different ways. Can `ring_iso_imp_img_ring` (see my updated answer) improve these?

Comment: My use of `obtains` is based on mathematicians' bias to define something by its properties rather than its construction whenever feasible. It's a questionable practice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my third attempt, using a neat lemma I discovered called `ring_iso_imp_img_ring`:

```
theory InducedRing
  imports "HOL-Algebra.QuotRing"
begin

lemma induced_ring:
  assumes ring_R: "ring ℛ" and phi_bij: "bij_betw φ (carrier ℛ) S"
  obtains  where "ring " and "carrier  = S" and "φ ∈ ring_hom ℛ "
proof -
  interpret R_: ring ℛ by (rule ring_R)

  let ?R = "carrier ℛ"
  define ψ where "ψ = the_inv_into ?R φ"
  have [simp]: "r∈?R ⟹ ψ (φ r) = r" for r by (metis ψ_def phi_bij bij_betw_def the_inv_into_f_eq)
  define S_add where [simp]: "S_add x' y' = φ (ψ x' ⊕⇘ℛ⇙ ψ y')" for x' y'
  define S_zero where "S_zero = φ ⇘ℛ⇙"
  define S_mult where [simp]: "S_mult x' y' = φ (ψ x' ⊗⇘ℛ⇙ ψ y')" for x' y'
  define S_one where [simp]: "S_one = φ ⇘ℛ⇙"
  define  where " = ⦇carrier = S, mult = S_mult, one = S_one, zero = S_zero, add = S_add,
                       … = m::'d⦈"
  have φ_in_ring_hom: "φ ∈ ring_hom ℛ "
  proof (auto simp add: ring_hom_def _def)
    fix x assume x: "x ∈ ?R"
    show "φ x ∈ S" using bij_betwE phi_bij x by auto
  qed

  have carrier_S: "carrier  = S" by (simp add: _def)

  have φ_in_ring_iso: "φ ∈ ring_iso ℛ "
    using φ_in_ring_hom ring_iso_def phi_bij carrier_S by blast
  have [simp]: "⦇zero := φ ⇘ℛ⇙⦈ = "
    apply (rule ring.equality, simp_all)
    using S_zero_def _def by auto
  interpret _: ring  using R_.ring_iso_imp_img_ring[OF φ_in_ring_iso] by simp

  show ?thesis using that[OF _.is_ring carrier_S φ_in_ring_hom] .
qed
end
```

---

**Previous version**

Here's my second attempt. It's somewhat more streamlined than my first, but I'm still hoping someone can come up with a much simpler way to do this that does not require restating and verifying the ring axioms one-by-one (in some cases, multiple times).

```
theory InducedRing
  imports "HOL-Algebra.Ring"
begin

lemma
  assumes ring_R: "ring ℛ" and phi_bij: "bij_betw φ (carrier ℛ) S"
  obtains  where "ring " and "carrier  = S" and "φ ∈ ring_hom ℛ "
proof -
  interpret R_: ring ℛ by (rule ring_R)
  let ?R = "carrier ℛ"
  define ψ where "ψ = the_inv_into ?R φ"
  have [simp]: "r∈?R ⟹ ψ (φ r) = r" for r by (metis ψ_def phi_bij bij_betw_def the_inv_into_f_eq)
  have [simp]: "s∈ S ⟹ φ (ψ s) = s" for s by (metis ψ_def phi_bij f_the_inv_into_f_bij_betw)
  define S_add where [simp]: "S_add x' y' = φ (ψ x' ⊕⇘ℛ⇙ ψ y')" for x' y'
  then have S_add_closed: "⟦x'∈S; y'∈S⟧ ⟹ S_add x' y' ∈ S" for x' y'
    by (metis R_.add.m_closed ψ_def bij_betwE bij_betw_the_inv_into phi_bij)
  define S_zero where [simp]: "S_zero = φ ⇘ℛ⇙"
  then have S_zero_closed: "S_zero ∈ S" using bij_betwE phi_bij by blast
  define S_mult where [simp]: "S_mult x' y' = φ (ψ x' ⊗⇘ℛ⇙ ψ y')" for x' y'
  then have S_mult_closed: "⟦x'∈S; y'∈S⟧ ⟹ S_mult x' y' ∈ S" for x' y'
    by (metis R_.m_closed ψ_def bij_betwE bij_betw_the_inv_into phi_bij)
  define S_one where [simp]: "S_one = φ ⇘ℛ⇙"
  then have S_one_closed: "S_one ∈ S" using bij_betwE phi_bij by blast
  define  where " = ⦇carrier = S, mult = S_mult, one = S_one, zero = S_zero, add = S_add,
                       … = m::'d⦈"
  have φ_in_ring_hom: "φ ∈ ring_hom ℛ "
  proof (auto simp add: ring_hom_def _def)
    fix x assume x: "x ∈ ?R"
    show "φ x ∈ S" using bij_betwE phi_bij x by auto
  qed
  have carrier_S: "carrier  = S" by (simp add: _def)
  interpret _: ring 
  proof (unfold_locales, auto simp add: Units_def carrier_S)
    show "⇘⇙ ∈ S" using S_zero_closed _def by auto
    show "⇘⇙ ∈ S" using S_one_closed _def by auto

    fix x' assume x': "x' ∈ S"
    let ?x = "ψ x'"
    have x: "?x ∈ ?R" "φ ?x = x'"
      using x' apply (metis ψ_def bij_betw_apply bij_betw_the_inv_into phi_bij)
      using x' by auto
    show "⇘⇙ ⊗⇘⇙ x' = x'" "x' ⊗⇘⇙ ⇘⇙ = x'" "x' ⊕⇘⇙ ⇘⇙ = x'" "⇘⇙ ⊕⇘⇙ x' = x'"
      using φ_in_ring_hom by (simp_all add: _def x)
    show "∃mx'∈S. mx' ⊕⇘⇙ x' = ⇘⇙ ∧ x' ⊕⇘⇙ mx' = ⇘⇙"
    proof (rule, rule)
      let ?mx' = "φ (⊖⇘ℛ⇙ ?x)"
      show "?mx' ∈ S" using bij_betwE phi_bij x(1) by blast
      show "?mx' ⊕⇘⇙ x' = ⇘⇙" "x' ⊕⇘⇙ ?mx' = ⇘⇙"
        by (simp_all add: _def R_.l_neg R_.r_neg x(1))
    qed

    fix y' assume y': "y' ∈ S"
    let ?y = "ψ y'"
    have y: "?y ∈ ?R" "φ ?y = y'"
      using y' apply (metis ψ_def bij_betw_apply bij_betw_the_inv_into phi_bij)
      using y' by auto
    show "x' ⊗⇘⇙ y' ∈ S" using _def S_mult_closed by (simp add: x' y')
    show "x' ⊕⇘⇙ y' ∈ S" using _def S_add_closed by (simp add: x' y')
    show "x' ⊕⇘⇙ y' = y' ⊕⇘⇙ x'"
      using φ_in_ring_hom by (simp add: R_.add.m_comm _def x(1) y(1))

    fix z' assume z': "z' ∈ S"
    let ?z = "ψ z'"
    have z: "?z ∈ ?R" "φ ?z = z'"
      using z' apply (metis ψ_def bij_betw_apply bij_betw_the_inv_into phi_bij)
      using z' by auto
    show "(x' ⊕⇘⇙ y') ⊕⇘⇙ z' = x' ⊕⇘⇙ (y' ⊕⇘⇙ z')"
      using φ_in_ring_hom _def x(1) y(1) z(1) R_.add.m_assoc by simp
    show "x' ⊗⇘⇙ y' ⊗⇘⇙ z' = x' ⊗⇘⇙ (y' ⊗⇘⇙ z')"
      using φ_in_ring_hom _def x(1) y(1) z(1) R_.m_assoc by simp
    show "(x' ⊕⇘⇙ y') ⊗⇘⇙ z' = x' ⊗⇘⇙ z' ⊕⇘⇙ y' ⊗⇘⇙ z'"
      using ring_hom_add[OF φ_in_ring_hom] ring_hom_mult[OF φ_in_ring_hom] x y z
             R_.l_distr R_.add.m_closed R_.m_closed
      by (smt (verit, ccfv_threshold))
    show "z' ⊗⇘⇙ (x' ⊕⇘⇙ y') = z' ⊗⇘⇙ x' ⊕⇘⇙ z' ⊗⇘⇙ y'"
      using ring_hom_add[OF φ_in_ring_hom] ring_hom_mult[OF φ_in_ring_hom] x y z
             R_.r_distr R_.add.m_closed R_.m_closed
      by (smt (verit, ccfv_threshold))
  qed

  show ?thesis using that[of , OF _.ring_axioms carrier_S φ_in_ring_hom] .
qed
end
```